# Poco 1.4 WebSocket and firefox close connection automatically after few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, websocket, poco-libraries

i am using Poco 1.4 for creating websocket server application and HTMl5 based webgl application.

i am sending vertices data to the server application for normal computation since normal computation takes more time to complete and send back the result.

My problem is this

The browser firefox is closing the websocket connection before receiving the data from the server.

This happens only in firefox and IE but not with chrome browser.

The connection is closed only from the client browser not from the server.

I want browser not to close the connection automatically.

is it possible to send ping/ pong message to make it active.

Comment: What is your exact version? Problems with Firefox have been [fixed](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/110) in 1.4.6 and 1.6.x.

Comment: i am using this poco-1.4.7p1-all